# What would be the approach for determining whether these function is one to one or onto both or neither?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations, elementary-functions

1) f3: Z × Z → Z × Z. f3(x, y) = (x + 1, 2y)
2) f4: Z+ × Z+ → Z+. f4(x, y) = 2x + y − 1

I understand the conditions for a function to be onto and one-to-one but in this case I'm having trouble understanding how to read the function since it is given x,y would I just find an x value in the cartesian product Z (same with y) and plug it in to determine if the conditions hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check if $f(x,y)= f(w,z) \implies (x,y) = (w,z)$ or if it possible for $(x,y)= (w,z)$.  If the implication follows it's injective other wise it's not.

And to show if it is surjective I'd try $f(x,y)=(w,z)$ and to solve for $x,y$.  If $x,y$ *always* have a solution it's surjective.  If not, the its not.

Example:

$f_3(x,y) = (x+1, 2y)$ is that injective?

Suppose $(x+1, 2y) = (w+1, 2z)$.  Then $x+1 = w+1$ and subtracting $1$ from both side $x = w$ and $2y = 2z$ so dividing both sides by $2$ give $y = z$.  SO yes: if $(x+1,2y) =(w+1, 2z)$ then $(x,y) = (w,z)$ and it *is* injective.

Is it surjective.

Suppose $(x + 1, 2y) = (w,z)$.  The $x+1 =w$ and $x = w-1$.  And $2y = z$ and $y =\frac z 2$.  Is that *always* possible.  Well, no.  If $z$ is odd then $y=\frac z2$ is not an integer.  So it is impossible to have $f_3(x,y) = (w,z)$ if $z$ is odd.  So it is not surjective.

Comment: would positive integers include 0 (regarding the second question)?

Comment: No.  Zero is usually not considered a positive integer.  .... But there'll always be *some* book somewhere where it is.....

Comment: If $0$ were positive the $f_4(0,0) = -1$ so that wouldn't work (because $f_4 \not \to \mathbb Z^+$  But if $x \ge 1$ and $y\ge 1$ then $2x + y - 1 \ge 2$ so $f\to \mathbb Z^+$.  (but note $f(x,y) = 1$ is impossible).